# Bi Directional Relations in Java

Tags: java, oop, bidirectional

Here's my problem. I have a Task and a Tasklist.

```
public class Task {
  private Tasklist task list;

  public void setTasklist(Tasklist tasklist) {
   // the code
  }
}

public class Tasklist {
  private List<Task> tasks;

  public void addTask(Task task) {}
  public void removeTask(Task task) {} 
}
```

What I want is this: I want to update the tasklist once the user changes the tasklist variable of the the task

So if I execute

```
Tasklist myTasklist = new Tasklist();
Task myTask = new Task();
myTask.setTasklist(myTasklist);
```

I want to see this.

```
myTasklist.getTasks(); // => [myTask]
```

Vice versa if I add a Task to my Tasklist I want it to automatically update the tasks tasklist reference

```
Tasklist myTasklist = new Tasklist();
Task myTask = new Task();

myTasklist.addTask(myTask);

myTask.getTasklist(); // => myTasklist
```

I tried to solve the problem on my own, but I always ended up with a stack overflow.

Comment: You need to show the code that gives you StackOverflowError.

Comment: Does it have to be plain-Java? You could create an EMF Ecore Model, those provide "opposite-references".

Comment: Should tasks be allowed on more than one list?

Comment: To achieve what you want, create a method for adding to the list that can ONLY be called the task itself that assumes the task already has its list reference and create a method for adding a list to a task that can ONLY be called by the task list itself that assume the tasklist already has its list reference. This prevents your infinite recursion I'm assuming you saw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A task belongs to a list, a list knows its tasks. Easy stuff - there is only one thing missing: deciding who is adding what to what?

I mean, normally you add a *Task* to a *TaskList*, so what is the point to model it on the opposite way? I dare to remove the setTaskList method for the sake of simplicity.

Now it is clearly seen that you add a new task to a tasklist by calling add(). There is only one way to add a task to a tasklist - by calling add(). Once you add a task to a tasklist, this add method updates the task's taskList attribute.

```
public class Task {
  private TaskList taskList;
}

public class Tasklist {
  private List<Task> tasks;

  public void addTask(Task task) {
      tasks.add(task);
      task.taskList=this; // belongs to this list now
  }
  public void removeTask(Task task) {
      tasks.remove(task);
      task.taskList=null; // belongs to no tasklist
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't see that new perspective.

Answer (score 0):

... And you ended up on stackoverflow.

Cycle dependency is rarely a good idea. The question to ask yourself is : Can a task exists without a Tasklist ? Can a tasklist exist without knowledge of its tasks ?

The biggest problem is that you would have to deal with the possibility that the Tasklist keeps track of a task which is refered to another Tasklist.

However, for this poblem, you will get a stack overflow if the call you are marking to the TaskList will call something on the Task which will call back the same method of TaskList.